# I/O operation closed on file in python

Tags: python-3.x, file-io

I have to write a program that prompts the user to enter six test names and their scores and writes them to a text file named tests.txt. You must use a loop. Each input should be written to its own line in the file. The program should generate a confirmation message when done. When I run my program it works but then I get an error at the end saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/brittmoe09/Desktop/program6_1.py", line 34, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/brittmoe09/Desktop/program6_1.py", line 18, in main
    test_scores.write(name + '\n')
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
def main():

    test_scores = open('tests.txt', 'w')
    print('Entering six tests and scores')

for count in range(6):
    name = input('Enter a test name')
    score = int(input('Enter % score on this test'))

    while name != '':
        test_scores.write(name + '\n')
        test_scores.write(str(score) + '\n')
        test_scores.close()
        print('File was created successfully')
main()
```

Comment: Well you `close` the file **inside** the `while` loop? So the next iteration. This will fail...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did. Get rid of that 2nd while loop, and move the close file out of the for loop because you are closing the file in the loop which is giving you the error: (some of my variable names are different than yours so look out for that)

```
test_scores = open('tests.txt','w')#open txt file
print('Entering six tests and scores')


for count in range(6):#for loop to ask the user 6 times
    name = input('Enter a test name: ')
    testscore = int(input('Enter % score on this test: '))
    for count2 in range(1):
        test_scores.write(str(name) + '\n')
        test_scores.write(str(testscore) + '\n')
test_scores.close()#close the txt file
print('File was created successfully!')
```

Answer (score 0):

the block while:

```html
while name != '':
  ...
```

This is an infinity loop if your "name" != '', so in first loop the file closed and second loop you get an error